# Can Craft be run on NearlyFreeSpeech.NET?

Tags: hosting

Because of some restrictions, some popular software (even Wordpress is a challenge) can't be run on NearlyFreeSpeech.NET. Can Craft be run on NearlyFreeSpeech.NET?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to run Craft CMS NearlyFreeSpeech.NET. I did it as follows:

- Place the Craft folder in /home/tmp.
- Place the files in the public folder in /home/public.
- Change the permissions of the craft folder and all subfolders and all files to 777.
- Change craftPath in index.php to '../tmp/craft'.

Perhaps it would not be necessary to change all subdirectories and files in the craft folder to 777. But it is the easier way and it should hopefully not create a problem, because the folder is not accessible from the public. Even the update process is running if the folder (including subfolders and files) is 777.

Comment: Also had to set cpresources within the public folder to 777 permissions. Other than that great guide!